# Push notification dose not work when APP is in background but not suspended and when APP is open

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

In android and iOS push notification doesn't pop up when a new push is received on the APP when App is in foreground/ Open or when it is in background but not suspended( Not killed).

To receive a new push pop up I need to kill the app then only i would receive it.

I'm using the following plug-in for cordova:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Cordova version:
5.3.1

I did try to find a solution for this if anyone could point me in right direction then it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this plugin works this way, the onreceived javascript event is triggered, but the notification is not displayed in the notification bar when the app is in foreground.

In android, in the last version, you can change this behaviour, doing your init like this:

```
that.push = PushNotification.init({ 
                        "android": {
                            "senderID": that.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID,
                            "iconColor": "gray",
                            "icon": "icon_notification",
                            "forceShow": true
                        },
                        "ios": {}, 
                        "windows": {} 
                });
```

the forceShow, allows the app to show the notification when the app is in foreground.

In IOS is not possible in this moment, there is a pull request to achieve that, for the 1.6 version, but I tryied the code and I have been unable to make it work

Here you have the link

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/pull/383

By the moment, I did a workarround in IOS, showing fake notifications via JS, with this library

http://taitems.github.io/UX-Lab/iOSNotification/index.html

Also, I dont know why the notification doesn't show when the APP is suspended, This happens in both Android and IOS?

In IOS, you have to add the capabilities of push notifications, and background modes -> background fetch and remote notifications. Maybe this is your problem.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks!!! Now I'm getting somewhere :). Is there a way to get notification in the tray even if the APP is open/ foreground.

Comment: Yes, with the forceShow param, but only for android

Answer (score 0):

i have not used cordova but answer you for clue that may help you.

Click [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) for more detail

Notifications are delivered to the **notification tray** when the **app is inactive**. For an active iOS app, notifications are instead passed to didReceiveRemoteNotification:. For **an active Android app**, notification payloads are passed to **onMessageReceived()** under the notification key in the data bundle.

So the json sending from server you should follow [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table2)
specially key "click_action".